# Prometheus Connection issue with Confluent Platform 5.1.4

Tags: java, apache-kafka, prometheus, prometheus-java

After upgrading our confluent kafka from `3.3.2` to `5.1.4`, not able to start the broker with prometheus JMX exporter java agent configured

```
-javaagent:/<somepath>/jmx_prometheus_javaagent 0.9.jar=0.0.0.0:7072:/<somepath>/kafkaconf.yaml"
```

Not able to get metrics posted into prometheus server as configured. There are few warn traces in the log as below.

```
2019-03-18 03:06:32.170:WARN:ipjsoeji.nio:Dispatched Failed! SCEP@3dc456f0{l(/IP_ADDRESS:52802)<->r(/IP2_ADDRESS:7072),d=false,open=true,ishut=false,oshut=false,rb=false,wb=false,w=true,i=0}-{AsyncHttpConnection@3833a47a,g=HttpGenerator{s=0,h=-1,b=-1,c=-1},p=HttpParser{s=-14,l=0,c=0},r=0} to io.prometheus.jmx.shaded.org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector$ConnectorSelectorManager@67c3a941
```

Please let us know your advice, if anyone come across such issue with Prometheus monitoring

Comment: could you put more logging statements?

Comment: Is there a Kafka connector for Prometheus?

Comment: @powder366 That probably should be a separate post... But sure, you could write a connector that writes data to PushGateway

Comment: A JavaAgent should work the same with any version of Kafka. This seems to be more issue with Prometheus than Kafka/Confluent

Comment: I wanted to know id there was an existing connector. When you say Java Agent are you meaning the jmx_exporter?